# Why Stream.ReadByte return int?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I spent some time on research `System.IO` namespace and after that I've found some interesting place for me. `Stream` class contains method with name [ReadByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx) and definition like that:

```
public virtual int ReadByte()
```

So actually my question is why method called `ReadByte` and returns `int`?
What is the purpose of naming like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ReadByte` returns

> The unsigned byte cast to an `Int32`, or -1 if at the end of the stream.

Such approach (having a special value which does not collide with any possible `byte` value) leads to use of a an integral type which "extends" `byte`.

In principle, types like `short` would work as well, but it is much more natural and conventional to use `int`.

Comment: What does "natural" mean here?

Comment: @dumbledad "_Natural and conventional_" in the sense that there is a common practice in C# to use `int`, unless there is a really good reason to prefer another intergral type (like `short` or `uint`).